# N-Tier Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-5

The N-Tier Entity Framework is an architectural framework to build custom applications based on the Microsoft Entity Framework.

i create sample application by N-Tier Entity Framework Generator .

https://ntieref.codeplex.com/

this apps work perfect by wcf remote connectivity. 
but it's don't have suitable performance for local ( direct connect Entity Frame work to local database ) .can i use this project for both local and remote connect to database ?

i dont know any solution for this problem .

Answer (score 0):

The N-Tier Entity Framework provides two configurations out-of-the-box:

- remote: connect client and server via WCF
- in-process: run client and server on a single tier within the same process

The two configurations can easily be switched by using either of the two generated assemblies InProcessChannelFactory or RemoteChannelFactory. By default MEF is used to hook in channel factories and you may simply define which is used by deploying one or the other.

In terms of performance of the database connection N-Tier Entity Framework fully relies on Entity Framework. However, since adding an additional layer on top of EF, it also comes with a bit of overhead compared to plain EF.